# Error message overflowing mat-card and cannot access buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having a problem with a long error message, which is what the client wants even though it has been suggested a shorter message and log would suffice.

The issue is the error message goes off the screen and the client then cannot access the cancel button.  Is there a way in the scss or html to fix this in Angular?

The html

```
<mat-card>
  <div i18n="@@add-systems-form.add-system" *ngIf="!isFormSubmitted" class="subtitle-2 card-header">
    Add System Entitlements for {{(activeAccount$ | async)?.name}}
  </div>

  <mat-card-content class="card-content">
    <form [formGroup]="addSystemForm" *ngIf="!isFormSubmitted" (ngSubmit)="addSystem()">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label i18n="@@add-systems-form.sales-order-number">Sales Order Number</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="accountPONumber" spellcheck="false" required />
        <mat-error *ngIf="displayMessages.accountPONumber">{{displayMessages.accountPONumber}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label i18n="@@add-systems-form.part-number">Part Number</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="partNumber" [value]="selectedPartNumber" (selectionChange)="changeValue($event)" required>
          <mat-option>--</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let partNumber of partNumbers"
                      [value]="partNumber"
                      aria-label="partNumber"
                      i18n-aria-label="@@add-systems.partNumber-aria-label">
            {{partNumber.partNumber}} - {{partNumber.description}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="displayMessages.partNumber">{{displayMessages.partNumber}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label i18n="@@add-systems-form.comment">Comment (optional)</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="comment" spellcheck="false" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="displayMessages.comment">{{displayMessages.comment}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard" id="spreadsheet-form-field" hideRequiredMarker>
        <div id="label-section">
          <mat-label id="spread-sheet-label" i18n="@@add-systems-form.spread-sheet">
            Spreadsheet
          </mat-label>
          <lcd-info-flyout class="after-asterisk">
            <mat-card class="spreadsheet-card">
              <mat-card-title class="subtitle-2" i18n="@@add-systems-form.spreadsheet-reqs-must-title">
                Spreadsheet Format Requirements:
              </mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-content i18n="@@add-systems-form.spreadsheet-reqs-must">
                The file must be XLSX formatted and less than 2MB. Only the first visible sheet will be processed.
                You need two columns named "Product Name" and "Serial Number". Other columns or sheets will be ignored.
              </mat-card-content>
              <div class="sample"></div>
            </mat-card>
          </lcd-info-flyout>
        </div>
        <div id="input-section" (click)="fileInput.click()">
          <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileInput()" class="hide" [disabled]="isBusy" />
          <input matInput
                 type="text"
                 [disabled]="isBusy"
                 id="spreadsheet-input"
                 [(ngModel)]="fileName"
                 formControlName="spreadSheet"
                 spellcheck="false"
                 readonly />
          <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="accent" class="float-right" [disabled]="isBusy">
            <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-error *ngIf="displayMessages.spreadSheet">{{displayMessages.spreadSheet}}</mat-error>
      <button type="button" (click)="downloadTemplateSpreadsheet()" class="label-icon-button" [disabled]="isBusy">
        <mat-icon color="light-blue" i18n-aria-label="@@add-systems-form.download-template:Download">
          file_download
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-label i18n="@@add-systems-form.download-template" class="hand disable-select">Download a spreadsheet template
        </mat-label>
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="errorMessage" class="form-error">{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button mat-stroked-button (click)="cancel()" type="button"
                class="pill"
                i18n="@@add-systems-form.cancel"
                [disabled]="isBusy">
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button mat-flat-button color="accent" type="submit"
                [lcdSpinner]="isBusy" [disabled]="!addSystemForm.valid || isBusy || overSizedInputFile"
                class="pill accent-color"
                i18n="@@add-systems-form.save">
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div *ngIf="isFormSubmitted" class="center-text">
      <h2 i18n="@@add-systems-form.add-complete-title"> {{addSystemResponse.recordsProcessing}} systems submitted for entitlement.</h2>
      <p i18n="@@add-systems-form.add-complete-message">
        Your transaction id is <strong>{{addSystemResponse.id}}</strong>. An email will be sent when the transaction is complete.
      </p>
      <button mat-flat-button (click)="dismissDialog()" color="accent" type="button"
              class="pill accent-color"
              i18n="@@add-systems-form.OK">
        OK
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

the scss

```
@use "../../../../style/lcd-branding-colors.scss" as lcd;

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

mat-error.form-error {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.subtitle-2 {
  max-width: 35rem;
}

.form-error {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  & > * {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .buttons {
    text-align: right;
    button {
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
  }

  .mat-error.form-error {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    height: 20%;
    max-height: 30%;
    scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
}

#input-section,
#label-section {
  display: flex;
}

#spreadsheet-input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#spread-sheet-label::after {
  content: " *";
}

.after-asterisk {
  margin-top: -0.4rem;

  mat-card {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
  overflow: visible;
}

.spreadsheet-card {
  width: 30rem;
}

.sample {
  background-image: url(~src/assets/img/entitlements/SpreadsheetExample.webp);
  height: 6rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background-size: cover;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.label-icon-button {
  background: transparent;
  border: unset;
  color: unset;
  font-family: unset;
  font-size: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: lcd.$lcd-hyperlink-blue;
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
```

[image: Example of Error Scrolling Off Page]